# How to load a pyspark ML lib transformer model if I don't know the class name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have created a pyspark transformer (fitted model) say Logistic Regression Model and saved it.
Now say a new developer comes and somehow I did a bad job of not storing the model class name somewhere before hand. The new developer uses a decision tree model and tries to load the model. It throws the error and tells me something like.

`IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel but found class name org.apache.spark.ml.DecisionTreeModel'`.

How will the developer without any previous knowledge (except that it's a transformer) load a transformer model in pyspark and then read from metadata the type of class and then load the model using that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a workaround. Basically add the model to a Pipeline or Pipeline Model and save the pipeline. That way model class name is no more required when loading.